# Zip folder to Array of byte using Scala

Tags: java, arrays, scala, playframework

I am working on application where I have to convert .Zip folder to array of byte and I am using Scala and Play framework.

As of now I'm using,

```
val byteOfArray = Source.fromFile("resultZip.zip", "UTF-8").map(_.toByte).toArray
```

But when I am performing operation with byteOfArray I was getting error.

I have printed byteOfArray and found the result as below

> empty parser

can you please let me know is this the correct way to convert .zip to array of byte?

Also let me know if is there another good way to convert array of byte.

Comment: Use plain Java: [`Files.readAllBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: Are you trying to extract the zipped contents, or really just get the zip file itself?

Comment: @fge thanks but I don't want to use java solution I want to go with pure scala code.

Comment: @Chrish Martin I have .zip folder in my project structure and I want to convert that in Array of Byte for my next logic execution.

Comment: What do you mean by ".zip folder"? A .zip file which contains contents of a folder, a folder which contains .zip files, something else?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I mean a folder contains files and another folders having files in it.

Comment: In that case `Source.fromFile` simply won't work. It expects a file, not a folder. See my edited answer if I understood you correctly (it's still not really clear what you want) and look at the library documentation for more.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is incorrect. UTF-8 is a *text* encoding, and zip files are *binary* files. It might happen by accident that a zip file is a valid UTF-8 file, but even in this case UTF-8 can use multiple bytes for a single character which you'll then convert to a single byte. `Source` is only intended to work with text files (as you can see from the presence of encoding parameter, `Char` type use, etc.). There is nothing in the standard Scala library to work with binary IO.

If you really hate the idea of using Java standard library (you shouldn't; that's what any Scala solution is going to be based on, and it doesn't get less verbose than a single method call), use [better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files) (not tested, just based on README examples):

```
import better.files._

val file = File("resultZip.zip")
file.bytes.toArray // if you really need an Array and can't work with Iterator
```

but for this specific case it isn't a real win, you just need to add an extra dependency.

> I mean a folder contains files and another folders having files in it

If you have a folder which contains `.zip` files and possibly some others in nested folders, you can get all of them with

```
val zipFiles = File(directoryName).glob("**/*.zip")
```

and then

```
zipFiles.map(_.bytes.toArray)
```

will give you a `Seq[Array[Byte]]` containing all zip files as byte arrays. Modify to taste if you need to use file names and/or paths, etc. in further processing.

Comment: My .zip folder contains files and more than one folders only(not zip folders). It dose not  contains another .zip inside parent .zip folder.

Comment: Again, it isn't clear what you mean by ".zip folder", because zip is a _file_ format. "Folder which contains .zip files" (apparently not, based on above comment), ".zip file" (because they can be opened as if they were folders in File Explorer), or "folder with name which happens to end in .zip"? Or something else?

Comment: .Zip Folder Parent ->(if you extract parent zip foders, files and folder as follows) ---> 1) xml files, 2) .class files and xmls folders

Comment: You can't extract a folder. "xmls folders" doesn't make sense either.

Comment: There are just two possible situations, basically: 1. You have a zip file. Then see the first solution, or fge's comment (which is equivalent, but has no extra dependency). 2. You have a folder which contains zip files (and possibly something else). Then find the zip files using the second solution and go to 1 to deal with each file.

Comment: Note: if you zip a folder, what you get is a zip _file_.